# STRAGG for CLOB?

Tags: database, oracle, function, string-concatenation, clob

Is there some function that makes the same behavior of SYS.STRAGG in oracle but instead of returning VARCHAR (and being limited to the VARCHAR size), it returns a CLOB , and thus allows (virtually) infinite number of concatenated strings ?

for example , I have a query `select x from y where z` that returns 2.5M records and I want to return all these records concatenated together 1 shot

Comment: Always mention your **database version** up to four decimal places.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LISTAGG function: “result of string concatenation is too long”](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13795220/266304)? `stragg` is undocumented so you should be using `listagg` anyway, for shorter values.

Answer (score 1):

XML functions can be used for such aggregation but for 2.5M records it will be very slow.

Example:

```
SELECT
    rtrim(
        dbms_xmlgen.convert(
            extract(
                xmlroot(
                    xmlelement(
                        "x",
                        xmlagg(sys_xmlgen(object_name || ', '))
                    ),
                version '1.0'),
            '/x/ROW/text()').getclobval(),
        1),
    ', ') aggregated_data
FROM
    all_objects
```

You might consider to use `LISTAGG` for pre-aggregation of small row groups into VARCHARs smaller than 4000/32767 bytes and then use the XML aggregation for the final result.