# Aggregate result from Oracle request

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table looking like this :

```
Table: table_name

name   priority    day       hour
-------------------------------------
name1     1       monday     21:00
name2     3       tuesday    21:00
name3     1       monday     21:00
name4     2       monday     21:00
name5     2       sunday     22:00
name6     1       sunday     23:00
name7     1       thursday   00:00
name8     2       sunday     22:00
```

Is someone as any idea how I can do a request, then manipulate the result to aggregate the result as below (without the column header of course) :

```
priority    day       hour          name
-----------------------------------------------
   1       monday     21:00      name1,name3
   3       tuesday    21:00         name2
   2       monday     21:00         name4
   2       sunday     22:00      name5,name8
   1       sunday     23:00         name6
   1       thursday   00:00         name7
```

I want to group by priority **and** day **and** hour.

**Priority** can be 1 to 5.
**Day** can obviously be Monday to Sunday
**Hour** can obviously be any hours :)
**Name** can be anything.

At the end, I need a SQL query to write the formatted results into a file.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Why didn't it work? Please [edit] the question to describe the problems you've encountered This isn't a code-writing service!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround for the ORA-01489 you can use XMLAGG as a workaround as per this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29776035/oracle-ora-01489-result-of-string-concatenation-is-too-long)

with extract

```
 SET LONG 2000000
 SET pagesize 50000
 SELECT rtrim(xmlagg(XMLELEMENT(e,text,',').EXTRACT('//text()')
                     ).GetClobVal(),',') very_long_text
  FROM
   (SELECT to_char(to_date(level,'j'), 'jsp') text FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL < 250
    )
```

Comment: Your mix of lower case only and mixed case variable names is strange. You should decide for one type and be consistent. The convention in Perl is to use snake case like `$query_db`.

Comment: I'm just wondering why I have downvotes for the answer which returns the expected result for the question, whereas, the copy paste solution which does not return the proper answer from a different link is accepted ...

Answer (score -1):

`STRAGG` can be usefull

```
SELECT priority, day, hour, stragg(name)
FROM table_name
GROUP BY priority, day, hour
```

and if it is not sufficient use `LISTAGG`

```
SELECT priority, day, hour, LISTAGG(name, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY name)
FROM table_name
GROUP BY priority, day, hour
```

Comment: Stragg is not a standard oracle function. See this question:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37340183/stragg-in-oracle-database-11g-enterprise-edition-release-11-2-0-4-0-64bit-prod

Comment: LISTAGG seem to work !  
However I get the error :(   
    ORA-01489: result of string concatenation is too long
I suppose it's because I have oracle 11.2 ?   
Is there any way to avoid this error ? 
Thx

Comment: Ok, I am confused. You specify that you want to create a script in Perl, Python, Bash etc and also tag it as such, then someone gives a sql query, which I thought you knew, and that seems to be what you wanted? I will edit your question accordingly then.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard - I'm looking for one way or another ^^

Comment: @amanssan So do you not know how to do the sql query or need help to write a script running the query?

Comment: @GerhardBarnard - It's the first time I'm using LISTAGG in a request. So I'm learning how to use it. The result is OK with it but now I need to figure out how to avoid the limitation which get me the error ORA-01489.
I'm reading the link provided above to find the solution :)

Comment: Then have a look here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29776035/oracle-ora-01489-result-of-string-concatenation-is-too-long

Comment: Solved with XMLAGG !
Thx for your help !

Comment: @simbabque He cannot list the answer as correct as this did not solve it, the link I sent to him in the comments on using XMLAGG did.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard then add that as an answer. ;-)

Comment: @simbabque True. Will see if he comes back and vote for it then. Thanks

Comment: I added the vote but as @GerhardBarnard said, it was his answer which finally solved it.

Comment: @amanssan I will amend my answer and then you can select it as the correct one if you want.