# Oracle ListaGG, Top 3 most frequent values, given in one column, grouped by ID

Tags: sql, oracle, rank, listagg

I have a problem regarding SQL query , it can be done in "plain" SQL, but as I am sure that I need to use some group concatenation (can't use MySQL) so second option is ORACLE dialect as there will be Oracle database. Let's say we have following entities:

Table: Veterinarian visits

```
Visit_Id, 
Animal_id, 
Veterinarian_id, 
Sickness_code
```

Let's say there is 100 visits (100 visit_id) and each animal_id visits around 20 times.

I need to create a `SELECT` , grouped by Animal_id with 3 columns

- animal_id
- second shows aggregated amount of flu visits for this particular  animal (let's say flu, sickness_code = 5)
- 3rd column shows top three sicknesses codes for each animal (top 3 most often codes for this particular animal_id)

How to do it? First and second columns are easy, but third? I know that I need to use LISTAGG from Oracle, OVER PARTITION BY, COUNT and RANK, I  tried to tie it together but didn't work out as I expected :(  How should this query look like?

Comment: Hello!  Welcome to StackOverflow!  Could you post a small set of sample data, along with an example of what you'd like output?

Comment: Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) For example Instead of 100 visit use 10. two animal and each one get 5 visits. and show the result with TOP 2 result.

Comment: What is the desired output in the case of ties? For example, what if the third and fourth most common codes both appear 11 times? Which code should be chosen? Also, if two codes tie for first place, which should be shown first?

Answer (score 1):

I think the most natural way uses two levels of aggregation, along with a dash of window functions here and there:

```
select vas.animal,
       sum(case when sickness_code = 5 then cnt else 0 end) as numflu,
       listagg(case when seqnum <= 3 then sickness_code end, ',') within group (order by seqnum) as top3sicknesses
from (select animal, sickness_code, count(*) as cnt,
             row_number() over (partition by animal order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from visits
      group by animal, sickness_code
     ) vas
group by vas.animal;
```

This uses the fact that `listagg()` ignores `NULL` values.

Comment: Elegant solution with ignoring NULLs and saving subqueries(+1). Pls fix `order by count(*)` in the `row_number`. (`cnt` is not defined)

Answer (score 1):

Here sample data

```
create table VET as
select 
rownum+1 Visit_Id, 
mod(rownum+1,5) Animal_id, 
cast(NULL as number)  Veterinarian_id, 
trunc(10*dbms_random.value)+1 Sickness_code
from dual
connect by level <=100;
```

Query

basically the subqueries do the following:

aggregate count and calculate flu count (in all records of the animal)

calculate RANK (if you need realy only 3 records use ROW_NUMBER - see discussion below)

Filter top 3 RANKs

LISTAGGregate result

```
with agg as (
select Animal_id, Sickness_code, count(*) cnt,
sum(case when SICKNESS_CODE = 5 then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by animal_id) as cnt_flu
from vet
group by Animal_id, Sickness_code
), agg2 as (
select ANIMAL_ID, SICKNESS_CODE, CNT, cnt_flu,
rank() OVER (PARTITION BY ANIMAL_ID ORDER BY cnt DESC) rnk
from agg
), agg3 as (
select ANIMAL_ID, SICKNESS_CODE, CNT, CNT_FLU, RNK
from agg2
where rnk <= 3
)
select 
ANIMAL_ID, max(CNT_FLU) CNT_FLU,
LISTAGG(SICKNESS_CODE||'('||CNT||')', ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY rnk)  as   cnt_lts
from agg3
group by ANIMAL_ID 
order by 1;
```

gives

```
 ANIMAL_ID    CNT_FLU CNT_LTS                                     
---------- ---------- ---------------------------------------------
         0          1 6(5), 1(4), 9(3)                              
         1          1 1(5), 3(4), 2(3), 8(3)                        
         2          0 1(5), 10(3), 4(3), 6(3), 7(3)                 
         3          1 5(4), 2(3), 4(3), 7(3)                        
         4          1 2(5), 10(4), 1(2), 3(2), 5(2), 7(2), 8(2)
```

I intentionally show Sickness_code(count visits) to demonstarte that top 3 can have ties that you should handle.
Check the RANK function. Using `ROW_NUMBER` is not deterministic in this case.