# Bypass ORA-01489 on LISTAGG function use

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

Within PLSQL Developer v8.0.4 I'm running into an error when attempting to use the LISTAGG function with multiple

```
SELECT t.order_id, t.DT, t.component_id,
   LISTAGG(results_comment, '<br>') 
          WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY t.component_line, t.cmt_line DESC) 
       as Compiled_Order_Rpt
FROM order_cmt  t ;
```

I keep getting the following error:

```
ORA-01489: result of string concatenation is too long
```

Some of these are well over 4000--upwards of 15000. I've tried inserting into a table with CLOB field Type but error occurs prior to INSERT.  Is there any alternative or way to bypass ORA-01489?

Comment: Perhaps this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13795220/listagg-function-result-of-string-concatenation-is-too-long

Comment: Take a look especially at the `XMLAGG` solution proposed in one of the answers in the linked question.