# How to concatenate strings from two columns based on userid column and the result should contain distinct values?

Tags: sql, oracle

```
TABLE                       OUTPUT TABLE    

U_ID|PRODUCT|BRANCH          U_ID    RESULT
1   AL  8                      1     8~AL-BL+1~HG-IK
1   BL  8                      
1   HJ  1                     
1   IK  1                   
2   IK  6                   
2   Po  8                   
3   UY  6
```

As shown in the snippet strings from two columns should be concatenated based on u_id column and in this requirement the final concatenated string should be distinct..

It is a Oracle database

I tried using LISTAGG function but not getting result for two columns.. any idea will help me a lot.. thanks

Comment: is this Oracle DB or MySQL they are two different engines please tag as required not as what you think will get most views (Welcome to Stack Overflow)

Comment: @MartinBarker thanks.. its Oracle DB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be done, by eliminating duplicates from the  `listagg` strings:

```
       with data as (
select 1 as id,    'AL' as PRODUCT,   8 as BRANCH   from dual union all               
select 1 as id,    'BL' ,   1  from dual union all               
select 1 as id,    'HJ ',   1  from dual union all               
select 2 as id,    'IK' ,   5  from dual union all                   
select 2 as id,    'IK' ,   6  from dual union all                   
select 2 as id,    'Po' ,   8  from dual union all                   
select 3 as id,    'UY' ,   6  from dual
)
select id, PRODUCT||'~'||BRANCH as RESULT from( 
select id,
REGEXP_REPLACE(
listagg(PRODUCT,'-') within group (order by id), 
 '([^-]*)(-\1)+($|-)','\1\3') PRODUCT, 
REGEXP_REPLACE(
           (listagg( BRANCH,'-') within group (order by id)), 
           '([^-]*)(-\1)+($|-)','\1\3') BRANCH
 from data 
 group by id
 )
```

Credits  for duplicate eliminatuion must go to [jack douglass](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/696/eliminate-duplicates-in-listagg-oracle)

**Results:**

```
ID  Result
1   AL-BL-HJ~1-8
2   IK-Po~5-6-8
3   UY~6
```

Comment: Thanks.. but my table contains 10k records ..  so how to edit this part: '([^-]*)(-\1)+($|-)','\1\3') PRODUCT ... awaiting your reply!!

Comment: @kumar Did not understand your question. What exactly do you want to edit in the above part ? If you mean that your result string is too long .. then  you have a problem even without `regex_replace` part...

Comment: I am trying to say that I have 10k rows in by table.. so how to make the query work for that!!?     ... issue is that in ID column its multiple digit id's present..

Comment: @kumar So, what makes you think that this solution would not work for that 10k rows? Have you tried?  Explain ...

Comment: thanks a lot .. you saved my time :) ..... can you share a idea to store the result in a new table ...   awaiting your reply..

Comment: Reason is that I can able to get the result but cant able to extract in excel nor create into new table... because of the count..

Comment: @kumar How about `create table myresults as select ....` where `select ...` the select of the solution ...

Comment: @kumar  [result-of-string-concatenation-is-too-long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13795220/listagg-function-result-of-string-concatenation-is-too-long)

Answer (score 1):

This is tricky.  Oracle doesn't support `distinct` with `listagg()`, so you need to use subqueries:

```
select pu.u_id,
       (products || '~' || branches) as result
from (select u_id, listagg(product, '-') within group (order by product) as products
      from (select distinct u_id, product from t) pu
      group by u_id
     ) pu join
     (select u_id, listagg(branch, '-') within group (order by branch) as branches
      from (select distinct u_id, branch from t) bu
      group by u_id
     ) bu
     on pu.u_id = bu.u_id
group by pu.u_id;
```

EDIT:

There is another way to do this without so many subqueries:

```
select u_id,
       (listagg(case when seqnum_p = 1 then product end, '-') within group (order by product) ||
        '~' ||
        listagg(case when seqnum_b = 1 then branch end, '-') within group (order by branch)
       ) as result
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by u_id, product order by product) as seqnum_p,
             row_number() over (partition by u_id, branch order by branch) as seqnum_b
      from t
     ) t
group by u_id;
```

[Here](http://rextester.com/NML45365) is an example in rextester.

Comment: Thanks for your time...ORA-02000: missing WITHIN keyword
02000. 00000 -  "missing %s keyword"
Error at Line: 3 Column: 50     ..........    getting this error .. please share your views

Comment: @kumar . . . Yes, of course.  That syntax would need to be correct!

Comment: http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=515  ......   added WITHIN keyword but now getting ORA-00979 ..

Comment: For the EDIT query :    ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 3 Column: 9                   can you able to figure out!!!!

Comment: working great but the issue is that the row count is large so how to make the result in a new table .. awaiting your reply!!

Comment: @kumar . . . You just put `create table <tablename> as ` before the query.