# does oracle have a length limit for concatenation

Tags: oracle

Is there a length limit (like the infamous 4000 byte) for the resulting concatenation with

```
'a' || 'b' || ...
```

and

```
concat(concat(concat ('a', 'b'), 'c'), ...)
```

thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LISTAGG function: "result of string concatenation is too long"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13795220/listagg-function-result-of-string-concatenation-is-too-long)

Comment: People have answered this question though in the context of the listagg  function performing the concatenation.

Comment: @PatrickBacon - the answer "in the context of LISTAGG" is not applicable to concatenation in general. Oracle can concatenate CLOBs, but LISTAGG cannot handle CLOBs.

Comment: @PatrickBacon i am aware of the listagg limit. This question is not related to that.

Comment: I read the question to narrowly (varchar2 scenario only).

Comment: @PatrickBacon yeah, that happens. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google is your friend - use it. The art is always in choosing the proper phrase to search on; maybe "Oracle concatenation operator" would work. You should see what the Oracle documentation says about your question. In short:

If you concatenate many single-character strings like you are, then yes, you will run into the 4000 byte limit for `VARCHAR2`.

If you want to exceed it, you must enclose at least one of the single-character strings within `TO_CLOB()` (or cast it to `CLOB` in some other way). Then there will be no limit to the number of bytes (NOTE: as you said, it is not CHARACTERS but BYTES - some people forget that) but, of course, the result will be a `CLOB`. There are many things you can do with `VARCHAR2` that you can't do with `CLOB` (you can't join on `CLOB` values, you can't group or order by a `CLOB` expression, etc.)