# How can i set a maxiumum value using list agg

Tags: oracle

i have read the other questions and answers and they do not help with my issue. i am asking if there is a way to set a limit on the number of results returned in listagg.

I am using this query

HR--Any baby with a HR<80 
AS

```
SELECT fm.y_inpatient_dat, h.pat_id, h.pat_enc_csn_id, 
LISTAGG(meas_value, '; ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY fm.recorded_time) 
abnormal_HR_values
from
ip_flwsht_meas fm
join pat_enc_hsp h on fm.y_inpatient_dat = h.inpatient_data_id
where fm.flo_meas_id in ('8' ) and (to_number(MEAS_VALUE) <80)
AND fm.recorded_time between (select start_date from dd) AND (select end_date from dd)
group by fm.y_inpatient_dat,h.pat_id, h.pat_enc_csn_id)
```

and I get the following error:

> ORA-01489: result of string concatenation is too long

**I have researched online how to set a size limit, but I can't seem to make it work. Can someone please advise how to set a limit so it does not exceed the 50 characters.**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do I get the following error LISTAGG function: “result of string concatenation is too long"?\*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53029759/why-do-i-get-the-following-error-listagg-function-result-of-string-concatenati)

Answer (score 2):

In Oracle 12.2, you can use `ON OVERFLOW ERROR` in the `LISTAGG`, like:

```
LISTAGG(meas_value, '; ' ON OVERFLOW ERROR) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY fm.recorded_time)
```

Then you can surround that with a `SUBSTR()` to get the first 50 characters.

Pre 12.2, you need to restructure the query to limit the number of rows that get seen by the `LISTAGG`.  Here is an example of that that uses `DBA_OBJECTS` (so people without your tables can run it).  It will only the 1st three values for each object type.

```
SELECT object_type, 
       listagg(object_name, ', ') within group ( order by object_name) first_three
FROM (
    SELECT object_type, 
           object_name, 
           row_number() over ( partition by object_type order by object_name ) ord
    FROM   dba_objects
    WHERE  owner = 'SYS'
    )
WHERE ord <= 3
GROUP BY object_type
ORDER BY object_type;
```

The idea is to number the row that you want to aggregate and then only aggregate the first X of them, where "X" is small enough not to overflow the max length on `VARCHAR2`.  "X" will depend on your data.

Or, if you don't want the truncation at 50 characters to happen mid-values and/or you don't know how many values are safe to allow, you can replace the `ord` expression with a `running_length` expression to keep a running count of the length and cap it off before it gets to your limit (of 50 chars).  That expression would be a `SUM(length()) OVER (...)`.  Like this:

```
SELECT object_type, 
       listagg(object_name, ', ') within group ( order by object_name) first_50_char,
FROM (
    SELECT object_type, 
           object_name, 
           sum(length(object_name || ', ')) 
              over ( partition by object_type order by object_name ) running_len
    FROM   dba_objects
    WHERE  owner = 'SYS'
    )
WHERE running_len <= 50+2  -- +2 because the last one won't have a trailing delimiter
GROUP BY object_type
ORDER BY object_type;
```

With your query, all that put together would look like this:

```
SELECT  y_inpatient_dat,
        pat_id,
        pat_enc_csn_id,
        LISTAGG(meas_value, '; ') WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY fm.recorded_time ) abnormal_HR_values
FROM (
    SELECT fm.y_inpatient_dat, 
           h.pat_id, 
           h.pat_enc_csn_id, 
           meas_value,
           fm.recorded_time,
           SUM(length(meas_value || '; ') OVER ( ORDER BY fm.recorded_time ) running_len
    FROM   ip_flwsht_meas fm
    INNER JOIN pat_enc_hsp h on fm.y_inpatient_dat = h.inpatient_data_id
    WHERE  fm.flo_meas_id in ('8' ) and (to_number(MEAS_VALUE) <80)
    AND    fm.recorded_time BETWEEN 
             (SELECT start_date FROM dd) AND (SELECT end_date FROM dd)
)
WHERE running_len <= 50+2
GROUP BY fm.y_inpatient_dat,h.pat_id, h.pat_enc_csn_id;
```