# Passing parameters into subquery raising invalid identifier

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I have a query in which I want to group by some fields and aggregate the last field within a CSV string. If you come from SQL Server like me, you would use `FOR XML PATH('')`. But in Oracle 12c that's a different story :

Table definition

```sql
CREATE TABLE HCF (
ID NUMBER,
HCF_DATE DATE,
HCF_TYPE_1 NUMBER,
HCF_TYPE_2 NUMBER)
```

Sample data

```
ID  HCF_DATE    HCF_TYPE_1 HCF_TYPE_2
272 27/02/18    1          1
279 28/02/18    15         2
280 28/02/18    15         2
283 28/02/18    5          1
```

The query I'm using

```sql
WITH CTE_HCF AS (
SELECT HCF_DATE, HCF_TYPE_1, HCF_TYPE_2, COUNT(ID)
FROM HCF
GROUP BY HCF_DATE, HCF_TYPE_1, HCF_TYPE_2
HAVING COUNT(ID) > 0
)

SELECT a.*, b.*
FROM CTE_HCF a
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT LTRIM(MAX(SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(ORDRE_ID,',')) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY curr),',') AS ids
    FROM ( SELECT HCF_DATE, HCF_TYPE_1, HCF_TYPE_2, ID,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY HCF_DATE ORDER BY HCF_TYPE_1, HCF_TYPE_2) AS curr,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY HCF_DATE ORDER BY HCF_TYPE_1, HCF_TYPE_2) -1 AS prev
            FROM CTE_HCF
            WHERE HCF_DATE = a.HCF_DATE AND HCF_TYPE_1 = a.HCF_TYPE_1 AND HCF_TYPE_2 = a.HCF_TYPE_2
        )
    CONNECT BY prev = PRIOR curr
    AND HCF_DATE = PRIOR HCF_DATE
    AND HCF_TYPE_1 = PRIOR HCF_TYPE_1
    AND HCF_TYPE_2 = PRIOR HCF_TYPE_2
    START WITH curr = 1 ) b
```

The error

```
ORA-00904: "a"."HCF_TYPE_2" :  invalid identifier
```

The desired output

```
HCF_DATE    HCF_TYPE_1 HCF_TYPE_2 IDS
27/02/18    1          1          272
28/02/18    15         2          279,280
28/02/18    5          1          283
```

I think that the problem is that fields from the original query are not visible in the sub query of the `CROSS APPLY` sub query.

PS : I have tried other ways described in [this article](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/string-aggregation-techniques) but I fail for multiple reasons like for `LISTAGG` it exceeds the xK number of characters. And I don't have sufficient privileges to create a function and `XMLAGG` might bring down your Oracle instance.

**Update**
Oracle version is : `Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0`

Comment: *"I think that the problem is that fields from the original query are not visible in the sub query"* Yeah, the attributes are only visible one layer down. So you could reference them in the WHERE clause of the inline view `b` but you're trying to reference them in a subquery nested within `b`.

Comment: `XMLAGG` might bring down your instance?

Comment: @APC referencing `HCF_TYPE_1` and `HCF_TYPE_2` in WHERE clause of the inline view `b` returns null. Also `ID` is `NUMBER` and there's no conversion to `CLOB`. Technically my data couldn't blow the max string size because when I calculate it manually the max CSV `IDS` is 2466 characters though the VARCHAR2 maximum is 32767 characters.

Comment: @ChrisSaxon `XMLAGG` consumes a lot of resources, I tested on a data sample and it used the hole available CPU. Check Erik Božič's comment on this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/29008456/3759822

Comment: When I said *"you could reference them in the WHERE clause of the inline view `b`"* what I meant was it's legal to reference them there, not that it would solve your problem. But then again, if technically your data *"couldn't blow the max string size because when I calculate it manually the max CSV IDS is 2466 characters"* what problem are you trying to solve? This is starting to sound like [an XY question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/133829).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I managed to ask the DBA to create a function that concatenates `id` values in CSV, which I personally think is the best approach to return a `CLOB` value.

The function :

```sql
create or replace FUNCTION concatenate_list (p_cursor IN  SYS_REFCURSOR)
  RETURN  CLOB
IS
  l_return  CLOB; 
  l_temp    CLOB;
BEGIN
  LOOP
    FETCH p_cursor
    INTO  l_temp;
    EXIT WHEN p_cursor%NOTFOUND;
    l_return := l_return || ',' || l_temp;
  END LOOP;
  RETURN LTRIM(l_return, ',');
END;
```

The query

```sql
WITH CTE_HCF AS (
SELECT HCF_DATE, HCF_TYPE_1, HCF_TYPE_2, COUNT(ID)
FROM HCF
GROUP BY HCF_DATE, HCF_TYPE_1, HCF_TYPE_2
HAVING COUNT(ID) > 0
)

SELECT a.*
  , concatenate_list(CURSOR(SELECT id FROM HCF WHERE HCF_DATE = a.HCF_DATE AND HCF_TYPE_1 = a.HCF_TYPE_1 AND HCF_TYPE_2 = a.HCF_TYPE_2)) AS CSV
FROM CTE_HCF a
```

[Source](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/string-aggregation-techniques)

PS : If you don't need a `CLOB` then `LISTAGG` is your best choice.

Answer (score 1):

If you're blowing out the character limit for `listagg`, how you handle this depends on what you want to display.

If you're on 12.2, you can use the on overflow truncate clause to trim characters that exceed the limit.

```
select hcf_date, hcf_type_1, hcf_type_2, 
       listagg ( id, ',' 
         on overflow truncate 
       ) within group ( 
         order by id
       ) csv
from   hcf
group  by hcf_date, hcf_type_1, hcf_type_2;

HCF_DATE               HCF_TYPE_1   HCF_TYPE_2   CSV       
27-FEB-2018 00:00:00                1             1 272        
28-FEB-2018 00:00:00                5             1 283        
28-FEB-2018 00:00:00               15             2 279,280
```

If you're on 12.1 there are [some other workarounds](https://blogs.oracle.com/datawarehousing/managing-overflows-in-listagg).

You can use row pattern matching (match_recognize) to find the length of the CSV for each extra row. And return those within the string limit:

I've added a couple of extra rows and set the character limit to 10 to show the principle:

```
insert into hcf values ( 281, to_date('28/02/18', 'dd/mm/yy'), 15, 2);
insert into hcf values ( 282, to_date('28/02/18', 'dd/mm/yy'), 15, 2);

with grps as ( 
  select *
  from   hcf match_recognize (
    partition by hcf_date, hcf_type_1, hcf_type_2
    order by id
    measures 
      sum(lengthb(s.id) + lengthb(';')) as len
    all rows per match
    after match skip past last row
    pattern (s+)
    define 
      s as 1=1
  )
)
  select hcf_date, hcf_type_1, hcf_type_2,
         listagg ( id, ',' ) 
           within group ( 
             order by id
           ) csv
  from   grps
  where  len <= 10
  group  by hcf_date, hcf_type_1, hcf_type_2;

HCF_DATE               HCF_TYPE_1   HCF_TYPE_2  CSV       
27-FEB-2018 00:00:00            1            1  272        
28-FEB-2018 00:00:00            5            1  283        
28-FEB-2018 00:00:00           15            2  279,280
```

Or you could split the rows into separate groups when you hit the character limit. And show them as separate CSVs:

```
with grps as ( 
  select *
  from   hcf match_recognize (
    partition by hcf_date, hcf_type_1, hcf_type_2
    order by id
    measures 
      match_number() as grp
    all rows per match
    after match skip past last row
    pattern (s csv*)
    define csv as 
      lengthb(s.id) + sum(lengthb(csv.id) + lengthb(';')) < = 10
  )
)
  select hcf_date, hcf_type_1, hcf_type_2,
         listagg ( id, ',' ) 
           within group ( 
             order by id
           ) csv
  from   grps
  group  by hcf_date, hcf_type_1, hcf_type_2, grp;

HCF_DATE               HCF_TYPE_1   HCF_TYPE_2  CSV       
27-FEB-2018 00:00:00            1            1  272        
28-FEB-2018 00:00:00            5            1  283        
28-FEB-2018 00:00:00           15            2  279,280    
28-FEB-2018 00:00:00           15            2  281,282
```

If you want to return the whole CSV list longer than the `varchar2` limit, you need to return a `clob`. Which you can do with XML:

```
select hcf_date, hcf_type_1, hcf_type_2,
       substr (
          xmlcast ( 
            xmlagg (
              xmlelement(s, ',' || id)
              order by id
            ) as clob
          ), 2
        ) csv
from    hcf
group  by hcf_date, hcf_type_1, hcf_type_2;  

HCF_DATE               HCF_TYPE_1   HCF_TYPE_2   CSV               
27-FEB-2018 00:00:00            1             1  272                
28-FEB-2018 00:00:00            5             1  283                
28-FEB-2018 00:00:00           15             2  279,280,281,282
```

Comment: I'm running 12.1 and truncating data is not an option for me, I have to return all the data. So I guess the best option according to your answer is returning a `CLOB` instead of a `varchar2` but how can I do it with `LISTAGG` ?

Comment: You can't. `Listagg` only returns `varchar2` (or `raw`). The limit for PL/SQL varchar2s is 32,767. The SQL limit is 4,000 bytes - unless you've enabled [extended data types](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/extended-data-types-12cR1)