# Concatenate values from SELECT with delimiter in ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle, select, sqlplus, listagg

I have table `products` and I would like to create strings:

```
http://localhost/app/feeds/send?type=myType&ids=1,2,3,...,100
http://localhost/app/feeds/send?type=myType&ids=101,102,103,...,200
```

I created sql query:

```
select concat('http://localhost/app/feeds/send?type=myType' || CHR(38) || 'ids=' , product_id) from products where isin like 'AC%' and status in
('Active', 'Created', 'Live')
and
((date>to_date('07.05.2021','dd.MM.yyyy') or date is null));
```

and it seems to be nearly what I need but result is:

```
http://localhost/app/feeds/send?type=myType&ids=1
http://localhost/app/feeds/send?type=myType&ids=2
http://localhost/app/feeds/send?type=myType&ids=3
```

how can I change this query to return 100 `ids` with delimiter `,`?

Comment: Sample data would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the LISTAGG function in Oracle.

```
select 'http://localhost/app/feeds/send?type=myType' || CHR(38) || 'ids=' ||

  LISTAGG(product_id,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY product_id)

from products where isin like 'AC%' and status in
('Active', 'Created', 'Live')
and
((pdate>to_date('07.05.2021','dd.MM.yyyy') or pdate is null));
```

[DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5251dc79c00ac9e16a68f44e2a5e5f73)

Comment: do you also know how to group by 100 rows? Without it ORA-01489: result of string concatenation is too long.

I can add `and ROWNUM <= 100;` but then there are only 100 rows, not like in a loop

Comment: I used this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40754382/4952262

Answer (score 1):

Drop the Concat function, you don't need it.

Add a Group By clause using whatever fields separate ids 1 to 100 from 101 to 200.

Then have your query return a column using ListAgg()  aggregate function like ListAgg(id,',').  The first parameter is the field you are aggregating (id), and the second is the separator to use between two records.