# how to write alternative query for listagg using querydsl

Tags: java, oracle, jpa, querydsl

I wrote query DSL DB query for below Oracle SQL query, it was working fine but when result string too long than 4000 it gives me an error, so I was found another way to do that, it is attached below and I need to write that query using query DSL and I don't know how to do that can you help me to do it?
below I attached detailed queries.

sql listagg query

```
listagg(to_char(qTable.AVAIL_DATE,'DD.MM.YYYY'),',') within group (order by qTable.AVAIL_DATE asc) availableDate,
```

querydsl code for above query

```
SQLExpressions.listagg( Expressions.stringTemplate(
                        "to_char({0},'{1s}')",qTable.availDate, ConstantImpl.create("DD.MM.YYYY")), "," ).withinGroup().orderBy( qTable.availDate ).getValue()
                              .as( "availableDate" ),
```

when string is too long it is giving me below error

```
ORA-01489: result of string concatenation is too long
01489. 00000 -  "result of string concatenation is too long"
*Cause:    String concatenation result is more than the maximum size.
*Action:   Make sure that the result is less than the maximum size.
```

found below alternative way to do the above task without mentioned error, need to help write the above query as below way.

```
SELECT RTRIM(XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(E,qTable.availDate,',').EXTRACT('//text()') ORDER BY colname).GetClobVal(),',') AS LIST
FROM qTable;
```

Comment: This question is about Oracle database, not MySQL, so I have removed the [tag:mysql] tag and references to MySQL. I know Oracle Corp. owns MySQL, but MySQL is not the same software as Oracle database, and they each support different functions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [LISTAGG function: "result of string concatenation is too long"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13795220/listagg-function-result-of-string-concatenation-is-too-long)

Comment: yes that is the answer but I need to write that using querydsl