# How can I structure this Oracle SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle, listagg

I need to retrieve the name or names of "CARGO#" separated by “,” filtered by "PNTO_VNTA"

I need the output in this way:

[image: I need the output in this way]

I have done many tests but they bring me the result in this way:

[image: I have done many tests but they bring me the result in this way]

This is the code that I am using

```
 SELECT
    s.PNTO_VNTA,
    LISTAGG (g.CARGO), ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY g.CARGO) OVER()  PRODUCTOS
FROM
    PNTOS_VNTA s,
    CARGOS g
WHERE
    s.crgo = g.CARGO
    AND s.PNTO_VNTA = 12345
    GROUP BY s.PNTO_VNTA,
    g.cargo
    ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are grouping by both `pnto_vnta` and `cargo`, so you will get one row for each combination; the aggregate would then only have a single value. You seem to have tried to compensate for that by adding the `over()` clause to make the `listagg()` call analytic.

If you change both of those you should get what you want:

```
SELECT
    s.PNTO_VNTA,
    LISTAGG (g.CARGO, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY g.CARGO) PRODUCTOS
FROM
    PNTOS_VNTA s,
    CARGOS g
WHERE
    s.crgo = g.CARGO
    AND s.PNTO_VNTA = 12345
    GROUP BY s.PNTO_VNTA
    ;
```

Or with ANSI join syntax:

```
SELECT
    s.PNTO_VNTA,
    LISTAGG (g.CARGO, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY g.CARGO) PRODUCTOS
FROM PNTOS_VNTA s
JOIN CARGOS g ON s.crgo = g.CARGO
WHERE s.PNTO_VNTA = 12345
GROUP BY s.PNTO_VNTA
;
```

Although it doesn't look like you need the join; unless you have nulls or orphans you can probably just do:

```
SELECT
    s.PNTO_VNTA,
    LISTAGG (s.CRGO, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY s.CRGO) PRODUCTOS
FROM PNTOS_VNTA s
WHERE s.PNTO_VNTA = 12345
GROUP BY s.PNTO_VNTA
;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=55c5458f59b4b357c069e807793416bc)

(I've left `s.crgo` in all of those; not sure if that's a typo in your question.)

Comment: Thanks for answering, I've tried your solution getting rid of the `over()` but when I do that I get this error `ORA-01489: string concatenation result is too long`

Comment: You shouldn't for the example you showed, as it only has three cargo values. If you have other (real) `pnto_vnta` values that have a lot of `cargo` values then those would have exceeded the 4k string limit with the analytic version too. That's a different issue though, and has been asked many times before - [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13795220/266304) for example.

Comment: I know for the first example I shouldn't get that error, but I still get it and don't know why, and I tried adding this `rownum = 1`  but I get only one result in `cargo`

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I've added a db<>fiddle showing that it works. If you are doing something more complicated then as a new question with a [mcve] - including the DDL and sample data that demonstrates the problem.