# Oracle SQL: length limitation of LISTAGG with CASE

Tags: sql, oracle

I use `listagg`combined with `case when` as aggretation as follows:

```sql
Select 
date as "Some Date",
sum(case when status = 'active' then 1 else 0 end) as "active id numbers",
listagg(case when status = 'active' then id_number END, ',') within group (order by id_number) as "List of active id numbers"
from mytable
group by date;
```

Result:

| Date | Active id numbers | List of active id numbers |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2021 | 4 | 2334,123,5123,13 |
| 01/02/2021 | 6 | 4213,14123,13,1235,126,745 |
| 01/03/2021 | 2 | 416,754 |

It works like a charm, unless the result is too long, as `listagg`is limited to 4000 bytes.

I cannot use `on overflow truncate` to truncate the `listagg` resultset, as I really need the full result.

In [LISTAGG function: "result of string concatenation is too long"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13795220/listagg-function-result-of-string-concatenation-is-too-long) it was suggested to generally replace `listagg` with `xmlagg`, to receive a CLOB instead, which would work for me.

However, I do not manage to correctly replace my `listagg` with `xmlagg`, as the `case when` statement does not seem to work.

This does not work: (error: 'missing keyword')

```sql
Select 
date as "Some Date",
sum(case when status = 'active' then 1 else 0 end) as "active id numbers",
RTRIM(XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(E,case when status = 'active' then id_number,',').EXTRACT('//text()') ORDER BY id_number).GetClobVal(),',') AS LIST
from mytable
group by date;
```

Could you advice me on how to work out the listagg limitations in my case? Will `xmlagg` work at all with the `case when` statement?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the `END` keyword for the `CASE` expression:

```sql
Select date_column as "Some Date",
       sum(case when status = 'active' then 1 else 0 end) as "active id numbers",
       RTRIM(
         XMLAGG(
           XMLELEMENT(
             E,
             case when status = 'active' then id_number END,  -- Here
             ','
           ).EXTRACT('//text()')
           ORDER BY id_number
         ).GetClobVal(),
         ','
       ) AS LIST
from   mytable
group by date_column;
```

---

However, you could just add a `WHERE` filter:

```sql
Select date_column as "Some Date",
       COUNT(*) as "active id numbers",
       RTRIM(
         XMLAGG(
           XMLELEMENT(
             E,
             id_number,
             ','
           ).EXTRACT('//text()')
           ORDER BY id_number
         ).GetClobVal(),
         ','
       ) AS LIST
from   mytable
where  status = 'active'
group by date_column;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e02696fa1165f8de976668ac459f4b2b)*

Answer (score 0):

A simple option might be to use your current query - with `CASE`s but  without aggregations - as a "source" for query which actually *does* aggregations on values that are already prepared through `CASE`. Something like this:

```
WITH
   temp
   AS
      -- your current query, without aggregations
      (SELECT datum,
              CASE WHEN status = 'active' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END status,
              CASE WHEN status = 'active' THEN id_number END id_number
         FROM mytable)
  SELECT datum,
         SUM (status) AS active_id_numbers,
         RTRIM (
            XMLAGG (XMLELEMENT (e, id_number, ',').EXTRACT ('//text()')
                    ORDER BY id_number).getclobval (),
            ',') AS list
    FROM temp
GROUP BY datum
```