# Oracle SQL: LISTAGG vs. XMLAGG - different results when using CASE WHEN

Tags: sql, oracle

I try to use `listagg` over `xmlagg` to bypass the length limitation of 4000 bytes of `listagg`.

My statement  however includes a `case when`statement, causing different results:

```sql
Select date_column as "Some Date",
       sum(case when status = 'active' then 1 else 0 end) as "active id numbers",
       listagg(case when status = 'active' then id_number END, ',' on overflow truncate) within group (order by id_number) as "Listagg List of active id numbers"
       rtrim(xmlagg(xmlelement(e,case when status = 'active' then id_number END,',').extract('//text()') order by id_number).GetClobVal(),',') AS "Xmlagg List of active id numbers"
from   mytable
group by date_column;
```

Result:

| Date | Active id numbers | Listagg List of active id numbers | Xmlagg List of active id numbers |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2021 | 4 | 2334,12333,512333,611651 | 2334,,,,,12333,,,,512333,,611651,, |
| 01/02/2021 | 6 | 4213,6481,7900,16515,22060 | ,,,4213,,,6481,,,,,,7900,,16515,22060,,,,,, |
| 01/03/2021 | 2 | 416,754 | ,,,416,,,,,,,,754,,, |

I face two issues with xmlagg over listagg:

- apparently, the function of xmlagg would always trigger even if `case when` is not true, causing empty `,`  eliminators
- performance: it is much slower (~3 times the execution time)

Did I do some mistake with using `case when` within `xmlagg`?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If your database has `on overflow truncate` then it is possible to use extended varchar2 length with [`MAX_STRING_SIZE`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-D424D23B-0933-425F-BC69-9C0E6724693C.htm#REFRN10321)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I said in [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69390534/1509264), you could alternatively filter in the `WHERE` clause rather than using a `CASE` expression:

```sql
Select date_column as "Some Date",
       COUNT(*) as "active id numbers",
       RTRIM(
         XMLAGG(
           XMLELEMENT(
             E,
             id_number,
             ','
           ).EXTRACT('//text()')
           ORDER BY id_number
         ).GetClobVal(),
         ','
       ) AS LIST
from   mytable
where  status = 'active'
group by date_column;
```

That way you will not include the non-active values that will be converted to `null` by the `CASE` expression.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e02696fa1165f8de976668ac459f4b2b)*

Or, [you can use a custom aggregation function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43000237/1509264).

---

As for the difference, `LISTAGG` is [documented](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions089.htm#SQLRF30030) to ignore `NULL` values:

> The arguments to the function are subject to the following rules:
>
> - The `measure_expr` can be any expression. Null values in the measure column are ignored.

`XMLAGG` does the same:

> `XMLAgg` is an aggregate function. It takes a collection of XML fragments and returns an aggregated XML document. Any arguments that return null are dropped from the result.

However, if you do:

```sql
SELECT DUMP(XMLELEMENT(E, NULL, ',').EXTRACT('//text()')) FROM DUAL;
```

You will find that the output has `Typ=58` which is an `XMLTYPE` data type (and not a string) so the values being aggregated are not `NULL` and are not going to be ignored.

For example:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (value) AS
SELECT 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4 FROM DUAL;

Select LISTAGG(value, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ROWNUM) AS listagg_list,
       RTRIM(
         XMLAGG(
           XMLELEMENT(
             E,
             value,
             ','
           ).EXTRACT('//text()')
           ORDER BY ROWNUM
         ).GetClobVal(),
         ','
       ) AS xmlagg_list
from   table_name;
```

Outputs:

> | LISTAGG_LIST | XMLAGG_LIST |
> | --- | --- |
> | 1,2,4 | 1,2,,4 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4242e0622de6e2489837bfc4e80bda8d)*

And regarding performance, you are asking the `XMLAGG` solution to create XML elements and then extract the text from the XML element and then aggregate and convert the XMLType to a CLOB (rather than a smaller VARCHAR2) and then to strip trailing commas; it is unsurprising that, when it doing so much more work, that it takes longer.

Comment: Thanks, your answere solved the problem I stated in the other topic. I made this new question however to understand the differences between xmlagg vs listagg, I just wanted to understand if they behave differently in general with case when, and used my previous example.

Comment: @TeaCup Updated with differences.

Comment: @MTO great answer and very well explained, as always. A real privilege to read your answers. That is the greatness of SO, you help , but you also learn a lot.

Comment: XMLAGG *does* ignore NULL values, like all aggregate functions I believe.